# Android studio not opening on Linux;

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio

The error which pops up when I try to run Android studio on crunchbang 11 (Debian based).
I have Android Studio running on another computer with the same OS. The only difference I can say is that the the latter laptop has an Intel processor and the former has AMD.

```
 ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager' 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:158)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:46)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:244)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:570)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:225)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:199)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:371)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:508)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:150)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/BadPaddingException
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:195)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1174)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:624)
    at sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo.verify(SignerInfo.java:399)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:579)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:596)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:262)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:238)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:776)
    at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:215)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:206)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:206)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:187)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:233)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getService(ProviderList.java:331)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:157)
    at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.java:139)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.ConfirmingTrustManager.getSystemDefault(ConfirmingTrustManager.java:63)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.ConfirmingTrustManager.createForStorage(ConfirmingTrustManager.java:58)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.<init>(CertificateManager.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:530)
    ... 30 more
[   5057]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.2  Build #AI-135.1267975 
[   5057]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_11 
[   5057]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[   5057]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[   5058]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 
[   5058]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `javax-crypto.jar. Download it and add it to your classpath.